# How to disable GPS in android mobile programmatically?

Tags: android, gps

I need to disable GPS programmatically after some event, i am using following method, but i am not able to do it...

```
 private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(provider.contains("gps")){
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS Turned off..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Go to my answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740365/programmatically-turn-on-gps-in-android/20740483#20740483](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740365/programmatically-turn-on-gps-in-android/20740483#20740483)

Comment: @MD ya, but always keeping GPS on consumes battery power, so i wanted to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Try this for turning off GPS

```
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

But you can do it only on 2.3 our less version. you can not do it on 4.x  because it is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons. While there were some hacks, like the one in your question, that used to work, those security flaws have since been fixed.

Comment: so how could we achieve it in android 4.x ?

Comment: You can't but you can gave user option for turning on/off GPS  ... Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);

Comment: Could you give any reference where I can read about this fix in 4.X versions please?

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager L = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 

if (!L.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
     Intent I = new Intent( 
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
        startActivity(I);  
}
```