# How to enable mobile data in specific sim

Tags: android, dual-sim

I am working on enabling mobile data programmatically and I got the solution from here [How to enable/disable gps and mobile data in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752859/how-to-enable-disable-gps-and-mobile-data-in-android-programmatically). But now I want to enable data in particular sim if it is an dual sim mobile.

Comment: Rather leave this choice to the user. Or do you want to refund them for charges accrued due to you changing their settings?

Comment: @sstn: Jaison never mentioned he is developing an application for distribution. Though that might be his intention, i don't think it is fair to take it for granted.! He might be trying to implement something for his own use and all he need is suggestions on how to do that.!